# Motorola XT1562 kills my services

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-sensors, motorola

I developed an Android application for research purposes that logs data from the smartphone internal sensors (I run 14 services that register a broadcast receiver and collect the onReceive data) and periodically it syncs them with a backend. Everything works fine on many smartphone, OnePlus 3, Samsung Galaxy S4/5/6, with both Android 5.X and 6.X. I also fixed the problem with the doze modality on Marshmallow. The problem is that I'm not able to run it on the Motorola XT1562. It works for few minutes and then nothing, sensor data is not arriving to my application (broadcast receivers don't work anymore) and it seems that all the services are paused and resumed at random. Does this Motorola model have an ultra annoying doze modality?? Do you have any hint? Thank you

EDIT: actually from the developer settings on the phone I see that all the services are killed except two of them.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was not a problem related to the Motorola phone. The services were killed by the system due to lack of memory, the OnePlus 3 has 6GB while the Motorola only 2GB (by the way the 14 services together use only 30-40MB of ram). I solved by using `startForeground(NOTIFICATIONID, notification);` linking all the services to a notification. In this way, the service is not killed when the system needs resources. You can put the startForeground() call in onStartCommand of the services:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("iLog sta raccogliendo dati")
            .setContentText(String.format("Oggi hai usato l'app per %d ore e %d minuti", (int)sharedPreferences.getFloat(Constants.LOGGING_HOURS, 0.0f), (int)(sharedPreferences.getFloat(Constants.LOGGING_HOURS, 0.0f)*60)%60))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_bar)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOngoing(true);
    startForeground(Constants.MAINNOTIFICATIONID, builder.build());

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

and then remember to stop it in onDestroy():

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "stopping service");
    stopForeground(true);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```